# Facebook page tab FB.Canvas not working

Tags: facebook, scroll

I am using static html to use an iframe to embed my site.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="810px" height="2200px" src="http://domain" style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;" ></iframe>
```

Something like that. 
In my code, I am using

> FB.init({appId: "00000000", status: true, cookie: true});
>   FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,300)

However, it doesn't work. Seems that it does not take any effect. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call FB.init asynchronously, like this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
     appId: param('facebook_app_id'),
     frictionlessRequests: true,
     oauth: true,
     channelUrl: site_url('/channel.html')
   })
}
```

Also for improve scrolling in canvas use the following:

```
 FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(10);
```

Comment: Yes, actually I did. But it does not show any error in the console.

Comment: if it doesn't show any errors, the how do you know it's not working? did you set your app ID and channel.html address?

Comment: because it does not scroll down, and does not have any error message in the console. Yes, I did

Comment: same, is it coz i am using static html which embed my site using iframe? That means there are two iframe, so FB.Canvas does not work??